# how to toggle two divs from one component when clicked from two buttons in other component in angular2

Tags: angular

Here,requirement is when `showbtnContent()` is clicked from `app.component.html`, the two divs id='btn1Content' and id='btn2Content' of `child.component.html` should toggle. Here , selector `<app-child></app-child>` is passed in 
`app.component.html`. ie when btn1 is clicked div id='btn1Content' should show and div id='btn2Content' should hide and vice-versa.

```
app.component.html
----------------------
<button class='btn' (click)="showbtnContent('btn1');">btn1</btn>
<button class='btn' (click)="showbtnContent('btn2');">btn2</btn>
<app-child></app-child>

app.component.ts
-------------------
showbtnContent(btn){
if(btn === 'btn1'){
thisbtnContent = true;
}else{
 thisbtnContent = false;

}
}
child.component.html
-------------------
<div *ngIf='thisbtnContent' id='btn1Content'>jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj</div>  
<div *ngIf='!thisbtnContent id='btn2Content'>jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj</div>

child.component.ts
------------------------
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child'
});
thisbtnContent = true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass data to the child component from the parent `app.component` so that child will understand that it will toggle.

So declar `@Input` type variable in child component which will take inputs from parent component and toggle

```
app.component.html
----------------------
<button class='btn' (click)="showbtnContent('btn1');">btn1</btn>
<button class='btn' (click)="showbtnContent('btn2');">btn2</btn>
<app-child></app-child>

app.component.ts
-------------------
showbtnContent(btn){
  if(btn === 'btn1'){
    thisbtnContent = true;
  }else{
    thisbtnContent = false;
  }
}
```

Now as you want to pass `thisbtnContent` to child pass this while calling child component like below

```
<child1 [toggle]="thisbtnContent"></child1>
```

Now child component should catch the `toggle` as `@Input` in the child component.

```
child.component.html
-------------------
<div *ngIf='toggle' id='btn1Content'>jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj</div>  
<div *ngIf='!toggle' id='btn2Content'>jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj</div>

child.component.ts
------------------------
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child'
});
@Input() toggle;
```